# Allocate memory for a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Can someone give me an example of how to allocate memory for a vector? A couple of lines is all I need.
I have a vector that takes in 20-30 elements.. but when i try to cout it and compile it i only get the first couple of entries..

Comment: Do you have any code you could show? The last line of your question really confuses me

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you have made a mistake in your code. You probably shouldn't have to reserve space manually

Answer (score 86, accepted):

An [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) manages its own memory. You can use the [reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [resize()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) methods to have it allocate enough memory to fit a given amount of items:

```
std::vector<int> vec1;
vec1.reserve(30);  // Allocate space for 30 items, but vec1 is still empty.

std::vector<int> vec2;
vec2.resize(30);  // Allocate space for 30 items, and vec2 now contains 30 items.
```

Comment: to complete this post, `resize()` adds elements constructed with their default constructor (i.e. if the type is `Elem`, then `Elem()`)

Comment: @swegi, by default, yes. `resize()` can also take a second argument which will be copied into all the new elements.

Comment: But, if you're just using `.push_back()`, do you have to reallocate/resize?

Comment: @c650 If you know how many items there will be and this amount is not a small one then it's better to allocate enough space.

Comment: In C++11 you can just pass count in contructor: `std::vector<int>(1000)`.

Comment: @ShitalShah Sorry, but passing in the count in the constructor does not work as expected in many cases: It create the vector with `N` default-constructed elements, it doesn't just reserve some space, as `vec1.reserve(N)` does.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534311/examples-of-modern-c-in-action/534634#534634)
You use **list.reserve(n);**

Vector takes care of its memory, and you shouldn't really need to use reserve() at all. Its only really a performance improvement if you already know how large the vector list needs to be.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(110); // Not required, but improves initial loading performance

// Fill it with data
for(int n=0;n < 100; n++)
    v.push_back(n);

// Display the data
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it;
```